Different order of observing RMW of variables across threads
The following example is from this cppreference page on std memory orders:
 
std::atomic<bool> x = {false};
std::atomic<bool> y = {false};
std::atomic<int> z = {0};
 
void write_x()     // Thread 1
{
    x.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}
 
void write_y()     // Thread 2
{
    y.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}
 
void read_x_then_y()   // Thread 3
{
    while (!x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
        ;
    if (y.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
        ++z;
}
 
void read_y_then_x()    // Thread 4
{
    while (!y.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
        ;
    if (x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
        ++z;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread a(write_x);
    std::thread b(write_y);
    std::thread c(read_x_then_y);
    std::thread d(read_y_then_x);
    a.join(); b.join(); c.join(); d.join();
    assert(z.load() != 0); // will never happen
}


The reference says, that - any other memory order (other than seq_cst) can cause the assert to fail since the order of observing the writes of 'x' and 'y' in different threads can be different. I have gone through This question and multiple other similar questions, but none of them seem to address the question -
How does a thread (say T1) makes changes in some variables in a certain order, while another thread (say T2) sees those changes in an opposite order?
Say we were using acq_rel in the above example. If thread 1 runs before thread 2, then it shouldn't be possible for thread 4 to read 'y' as 1 and 'x' as 0 right? Similarly, if thread 2 runs before thread 1, then it shouldn't be possible for thread 3 to read 'x' as 1 and 'y' as 0.

Many answers seem to propose that this is because a store is not visible to all the cores immediately (or similar answers based on multi-level caches, store-buffers, etc)

BUT
If 1. is true, then what about a program like -
std::atomic<int> x;

// The two threads are running on different cores in parallel

// Thread 1 is running this function
void incx_thread1(){
    for (int a = 0; a < 1000000; a++) {
         x.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
}

// Thread 2 is running this function
void incx_thread2(){
    for (int a = 0; a < 1000000; a++) {
         x.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
}


If 1. were to be true, then the fetch_add of one thread need not be visible to the other thread. Thus, the final value of the variable 'x' need not be 2000000. But to the best of my knowledge (correct me if I am wrong), there is no need of a seq_cst memory order in the above program to make it correct. In the case of a single variable, the store from one thread is conveyed to the other thread. Why does the above program work without seq_cst?
I can't think of a case where a thread makes changes to variables in a certain order and the other one sees them in a different order (and the simple program above works).
Where am I wrong? Thanks in advance.

Atomic RMWs have an extra guarantee, that the load sees the "latest value" in the modification order of that object.  i.e. the one right before the modification done by the store side of the RMW.  Multiple RMWs on the same variable is a completely different situation than two independent writers writing different variables (in different cache lines for IRIW disagreement about ordering to be possible in practice).

I can't think of a case where a thread makes changes to variables in a certain order and the other one sees them in a different order (and the simple program above works). - Correct, every atomic object separately has a modification-order M that's consistent with values seen by all readers.  Things get interesting when you have multiple atomic objects and care about relative order of different ops on them, then you can have things like StoreStore reordering if both were written by the same thread for example (https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/)

Maybe this isn't just a duplicate of one of the IRIW Q&As; I was thinking at first the second half of the question was basically an unrelated separate question, but when commenting about that part I see you do somewhat tie the parts together.  Still, it's close to two separate questions (where an SO question should really only ask one) and the duplicate does answer how the IRIW litmus test can fail in practice on real CPUs.  I think the subject matter of the second part has been covered in other Q&As on stack overflow so I could try to find one to add to the dup list if you want.

or similar answers based on multi-level caches, - nope, caches are coherent between cores that C++ implementations run std::threads across.  Multi-level caches don't create IRIW reordering.  The key factor is a side channel separate from making a store visible to other cores through cache.

@PeterCordes 'that the load sees the "latest value" in the modification order of that object. i.e. the one right before the modification done by the store side of the RMW.' If thats the case, say: T1 ran before T2 making x true and y false. Then when T4 loads 'x', it will have to load the latest value of 'x' which is true right? So how will z ever become 0 if I use acq_rel?

@PeterCordes Indeed, I intended to interlink those two questions. Maybe I could have tried to rephrase the question in a better way. Essentially, even if the store is visible to some of the cores and not globally visible, then the simple program of incrementing 'x' will fail for that hardware right?

Your first code block doesn't have any atomic RMW operations (except ++z;), only pure-loads and pure-stores so none of that applies to the IRIW litmus test, only to the x.fetch_add code in your second block.  And each thread only reads or only writes atomic variables in the IRIW litmus test (again except for z).  It's common for people to get hung up on the "latest value" phrasing and think that implies something about seeing changes faster or there being a total order of all loads and stores; there isn't one unless you use seq_cst everywhere, just what's visible to any given thread.

Even the load side of an atomic RMW is special; CPU architects typically provide either a single-instruction RMW like on x86 or ARMv8.1, or LL/SC instructions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) you can put in a retry loop that retries until this core had exclusive ownership of the cache line from the load to the store, otherwise aborting the store.  The "latest value" phrasing is how the C++ formalism maps that hardware functionality into the C++ standard as a guarantee that atomic RMWs are atomic wrt. any other operations on the same object.

I linked some additional duplicates which cover the "last value" guarantee (https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics#order-10 since I just added the link to one of my existing answers.)  That guarantees RMW atomicity without putting restrictions on pure loads or pure stores.

Other related Q&As I didn't add as duplicates: relaxed ordering and inter thread visibility / Can't relaxed atomic fetch_add reorder with later loads on x86, like store can? / Atomic operation propagation/visibility (atomic load vs atomic RMW load)
